# Как удалить из массива повторяющиеся элементы?

Tags: javascript

Например:
`[8,2,2,5] => [8,2,5]`

- Массив не отсортирован.
- Повторяющиеся элементы всегда идут подряд.

Я придумал решение с двумя циклами и вторым массивом. Вот решил спросить может есть какое нибудь более элегантное решение.

Comment: Массив отсортирован?  Можно использовать готовые решения ( тот же lodash, например)

Comment: @AlexeyTen Сори за некорретный пример, нет, массив не отсортирован.

Comment: Это задачка случаем не с экзамена?

Comment: @t1nk Нет, я работаю.

Comment: [тесты выше перечисленных способов](https://jsbench.me/9djyzr25wz/1)

Comment: Как на счёт set?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Алгоритм с линейной асимптотикой.

В этой реализации изменяет исходный массив, но можно легко переделать на создание нового.

```
function doSmth(a) {
  for (var q=1, i=1; q<a.length; ++q) {
    if (a[q] !== a[q-1]) {
      a[i++] = a[q];
    }
  }

  a.length = i;
  return a;
}
```

Comment: здорово, не знал что `.length` можно устанавливать. Лаконично и эффективно!

Comment: @Sergiks А зачем устанавливать length поясните пожалуйста?

Comment: Тут вдоль массива идут два указателя: `q` (читает) и `i` (пишет). Когда начинается серия повторяющихся значений, `q` уходит вперёд. А `i` записывает по одному новому значению, отставая позади. В итоге,  всё, что левее `i` – уникальные значения по одному. Установка `.length = i` **обрезает массив** так, что остаются только элементы левее `i`.

Comment: @Sergiks А зачем использовать префиксную форму инкримента `++q` в цикле?

Comment: @Khipster здесь без разницы `++q` или `q++`.

Comment: @Khipster, а зачем использовать постфиксную?

Answer (score 15):

Короткое решение выглядит так:

```
uniqueArray = a.filter(function(item, pos) {
    return a.indexOf(item) == pos;
})
```

Чуть умнее можно так:

```
function uniq(a) {
    var seen = {};
    return a.filter(function(item) {
        return seen.hasOwnProperty(item) ? false : (seen[item] = true);
    });
}
```

Объединение этих двух подходов:

```
function uniq(a) {
    var prims = {"boolean":{}, "number":{}, "string":{}}, objs = [];

    return a.filter(function(item) {
        var type = typeof item;
        if(type in prims)
            return prims[type].hasOwnProperty(item) ? false : (prims[type][item] = true);
        else
            return objs.indexOf(item) >= 0 ? false : objs.push(item);
    });
}
```

Самое быстрое решение (без вызовов функций):

```
function uniq_fast(a) {
    var seen = {};
    var out = [];
    var len = a.length;
    var j = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
         var item = a[i];
         if(seen[item] !== 1) {
               seen[item] = 1;
               out[j++] = item;
         }
    }
    return out;
}
```

Источник со всеми подробностями: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9229821/2707359

Comment: Круто, я до такого трюка с filter и indexOf никогда бы не додумался. 5+ И по-моему этот метод будет ни чуть не медленнее чем последний.

Comment: @Khipster Надо только понимать, что это те же два цикла.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Ну и отлично. Массивы по идее быстрее чем объекты. Поэтому я вот сомневаюсь по поводу последнего самого быстрого метода где используется объект.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Зацени я забабахал самый быстрый способ https://jsfiddle.net/gx02o9nm/

Comment: @Khipster, это ужас. Во-первых, вы заменили в первом же вызове массив на отфильтрованный. Во-вторых, для массива из пары десятков элементов вы измеряете не алгоритм, а накладные расходы.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Признаю, с объектом быстрее... https://jsfiddle.net/gx02o9nm/1/

Comment: @Khipster вы всё ещё заменяете исходный массив. И где же самый быстрый вариант Sergiks/Qwertiy/мой?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Теперь без ошибок: https://jsfiddle.net/gx02o9nm/2/ Сейчас и ваш добавлю.

Answer (score 8):

Вариант с использованием [`Set` из ECMA2015](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) и [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

```js
var arr = [1,8,2,2,5,5,5,5,7];
document.write(JSON.stringify(arr),'<br/>');
var uniq = Array.from(new Set(arr));
document.write(JSON.stringify(uniq));
```

Comment: Эм.. А `Set` разве порядок элементов сохранит?

Comment: @Qwertiy, не уверен, на простом тесте - сохранял, но возможно это не гарантируется

Comment: Я прочитал. Сохраняет: "Объекты Set представляют коллекции значений, по который вы можете выполнить обход в порядке вставки элементов.". Неожиданно. Интересный ответ :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, добавил пример :)

Answer (score 3):

Учитывая, что повторы идут подряд, можно без дополнительного массива менять исходный: пройтись по элементам, запоминая предыдущий, и удаляя хвосты повторов:

```js
var a = [8,2,2,5]
  ,i = 0
  ,pValue       // предыдущее значение
  ,pStart       // первая позиция пред. зн.
  ,cValue       // текущее значение
  ,length = 0   // длина фрагмента с повторами
;
 
while( i++ < a.length) {
  cValue = a[i];
  if( pValue === cValue) {
    length++;
    continue;
  }

  if(length) {
    a.splice(pStart,length);
    i -= length;
  }
  pValue = cValue;
  pStart = i;
  length = 0;
}
if(length) a.splice(pStart,length);

document.body.innerText = JSON.stringify(a);
```

Comment: Как-то сложновато выглядит... Вроде [тот же подход](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/540010/178988)? Хотя нет, не тот. У меня перезаписываются элементы, что даёт линейную ассимптотику, а тут вырезаются куски из середины массива, что даёт квадратичную.

Comment: Да, усложнил. У вас на порядок красивее!

Answer (score 3):

Решение для вашего случая (все одинаковые элементы стоят рядом):

```
uniqArray = a.filter( (item, pos, arr) => !pos || item !== arr[pos - 1] );
```

Хотя я бы просто взял уже готовое решение https://lodash.com/docs#sortedUniq

Answer (score 3):

Еще один вариант,
получения уникальных элементов с помощью [спреда и сетки] т.е. [[Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) & [Set]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).
Оставлю здесь ↧ эту короткую строчку кода, может кому-то пригодится.

```
let uniАrr = [...new Set(arr)];
```

Эх, была не была...
На всякий случай добавлю пример.

```js
let arr = [8,2,2,5];
let uniАrr = [...new Set(arr)];

console.log(uniАrr);
```

Answer (score 3):

Если вы хотите выполнить итерацию по массиву с объектами, то используйте:

```js
let newArray = [{
  id: 1
}, {
  id: 2
}, {
  id: 3
}, {
  id: 3
}, {
  id: 3
}, {
  id: 2
}, {
  id: 2
}];
const filteredArray = [];
newArray.filter((item) => {
  if (!filteredArray.some((element) => element.id === item.id)) {
    filteredArray.push(item);
  }
});
console.log(filteredArray);
```

Comment: здесь принято общаться на русском языке. переведите, пожалуйста, ваш ответ, нажав [edit].

Answer (score -1):

По-моему самое лаконичное и красивое решение для современного JS (ES6+):

`Array.from(new Set([8,2,2,5]))`

В set-ах не могут храниться повторяющиеся элементы, поэтому преобразование массива в set и обратно просто выкидывает все лишние, сортировка при этом остаётся прежней.

Для IE способ не подойдёт из-за отсутствия в нём поддержки new Set(iterable), придётся перебирать вручную, либо найти полифилл.

Comment: уже есть такой ответ от @Grundy

Answer (score -1):

1. const unic = arr => new Set(arr)
2. const unic = arr => arr.filter((i, n) => !arr.includes(i, n + 1))

Answer (score -1):

```
const b = a.filter(function (item, position, array) {
  return array.lastIndexOf(item) === position; // вернём уникальные элементы
});
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]